# Anime shown on TV in the mid-'90s featuring a black robot hidden under a tennis court

Tags: story-identification, anime

This anime was running on TV in the mid-'90s and I don't remember much except that it included a black robot hidden under a tennis court, which had some yellow numbers on his shoulder, probably 88 or something similar. This was some time ago so unfortunately I don't remember more than that. All help much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like ***[The New Adventures of Gigantor](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458218/)*** (aka *New Tetsujin-28*).

From IMDB:

> At the beginning of the 21st century, scientists found that with new computers and super alloys, they could build an even bigger, faster Gigantor. They built the new Gigantor.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Adventures_of_Gigantor):

> *New Tetsujin-28* (太陽の使者 鉄人28号, Taiyō no Shisha Tetsujin Nijūhachi-gō, lit. Solar Messenger Iron Man #28) is a 1980 Japanese Mecha Animated series produced by Tokyo Movie Shinsha, and a modern style remake of Mitsuteru Yokoyama's manga Tetsujin 28-go.[3](https://youtu.be/AuceLU556dU?t=838) It was directed by Tetsuo Imazawa and produced by both Shigeru Akagawa and Toru Horikoshi. It aired on Nippon Television from October 3, 1980 to September 25, 1981 with a total count of 51 episodes. Fred Ladd and TMS converted the series into *The New Adventures of Gigantor*, which was broadcast on the Sci-Fi Channel in the United States from September 9, 1993 to June 30, 1997.

The show features a giant robot which emerges from beneath a tennis court, as shown in the video below around the 13:58 mark. The robot is mostly dark blue, with the number "28" printed on both arms in yellow.

Comment: Just want to let others know that [the YouTube video is geoblocked in some countries](https://polsy.org.uk/stuff/ytrestrict.cgi?ytid=https%3A%2F%2Fyoutu.be%2FAuceLU556dU%3Ft%3D838&auth=00cc178dfc1e8b7466d07bc9aa0ec19b) due to licensing.

Comment: hahahaha this is so crazy someone actually knew what I was talking about, this means the world to me and more, you're the best!